# How to refer to a char* instead of using char[] when using mysql_stmt_prepare

Tags: c

When trying to insert multiple records using C using bind parameter I can't get it working using `char * str_data` and then using malloc of strdup to set "test string". I have to define `char str_data[50]`. If I try to use `char * str_data` and `str_data = strdup("teststring")` it fills MySQL with random bytes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>

int main(void)
{
    MYSQL *con;
    con = mysql_init(NULL);

    my_bool reconnect = 1;
    mysql_options(con, MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT, &reconnect);

    if (mysql_real_connect(con, "127.0.0.1", "hidden", "hidden", "hidden", 0, NULL, 0) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
        mysql_close(con);
        exit(0);
    }

    MYSQL_STMT *stmt;
    MYSQL_BIND ps_params[1];
    char str_data[50];
    unsigned long str_length;

    stmt = mysql_stmt_init(con);
    mysql_stmt_prepare(stmt, "INSERT INTO `test` (two) VALUES (?)", strlen("INSERT INTO `test` (two) VALUES (?)"));
    memset(ps_params, 0, sizeof(ps_params));

    ps_params[0].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
    ps_params[0].buffer = (char *)&str_data;
    ps_params[0].buffer_length = 50;
    ps_params[0].length = &str_length;
    ps_params[0].is_null = 0;

    mysql_stmt_bind_param(stmt, ps_params);

    str_length = strlen("test string");
    strcpy(str_data, "test string");
    mysql_stmt_execute(stmt);

    mysql_close(con);

}
```

Can someone explain to me why using `char * str_data` and `str_data = strdup("teststring")` results in MySQL reading gibberish?

Edit:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>

int main(void)
{
    MYSQL *con;
    con = mysql_init(NULL);

    my_bool reconnect = 1;
    mysql_options(con, MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT, &reconnect);

    if (mysql_real_connect(con, "127.0.0.1", "hidden", "hidden", "hidden", 0, NULL, 0) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
        mysql_close(con);
        exit(0);
    }

    MYSQL_STMT *stmt;
    MYSQL_BIND ps_params[1];
    char * str_data;
    unsigned long str_length;

    stmt = mysql_stmt_init(con);
    mysql_stmt_prepare(stmt, "INSERT INTO `test` (two) VALUES (?)", strlen("INSERT INTO `test` (two) VALUES (?)"));
    memset(ps_params, 0, sizeof(ps_params));

    ps_params[0].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
    ps_params[0].buffer = (char *)&str_data;
    ps_params[0].buffer_length = (strlen("test string") + 1);
    ps_params[0].length = &str_length;
    ps_params[0].is_null = 0;

    mysql_stmt_bind_param(stmt, ps_params);

    str_length = strlen("test string");
    str_data = strdup("test string");
    mysql_stmt_execute(stmt);

    mysql_close(con);

}
```

result in database: `Ð|D     =N_`

result in `printf("'%s'\n", str_data)`: `'test string'`

I think it has something to do with `ps_params[0].buffer = (char *)&str_data;` being a pointer

Comment: Do you have warnings turn on in your compiler settings?  ( eg. -WALL )

Comment: Can show the `strdup` version code?

Comment: Can you also post the version of the code that uses `strdup()` and results in the garbled output?

Comment: @Z4-tier I've added the strdup version

Answer (score 0):

Here is the offending part of your code:

```
ps_params[0].buffer = (char *)&str_data;
```

`.buffer` should point to a memory buffer, but it points to an (unintialized) pointer.
The fact that you are using type-casting to get rid of a compiler warning, should be a hint that something is very wrong. *Never, ever, under any circumstances, use type casting, unless you know better than the compiler what is going on!*

So if `str_data` points to a buffer, just initialize `ps_params[0].buffer` with the *value* of `str_data` rather than the *address* of `str_data`. `.buffer` should point at "the same thing" that `str_data` points at, rather than *at* `str_data` itself. Like this:

```
ps_params[0].buffer = str_data;
```

The problem now, is that you haven't initialized `str_data` yet. It points to garbage, so now `ps_params[0].buffer` points to garbage too. You must therefore move the initialization of `str_data`  to before the assignment of `ps_params[0].buffer`:

```
char * str_data = strdup("test string");
unsigned long str_length = strlen(str_data);

stmt = mysql_stmt_init(con);
mysql_stmt_prepare(stmt, "INSERT INTO `test` (two) VALUES (?)", strlen("INSERT INTO `test` (two) VALUES (?)"));
memset(ps_params, 0, sizeof(ps_params));

ps_params[0].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
ps_params[0].buffer = str_data;
ps_params[0].buffer_length = str_len + 1;
ps_params[0].length = &str_length;
ps_params[0].is_null = 0;

mysql_stmt_bind_param(stmt, ps_params);

mysql_stmt_execute(stmt);

// `strdup` calls `malloc`, so we have to free the buffer after use
free(str_data); 

mysql_close(con);
```

Adding runtime error-checking is left as an exercise for the reader

Comment: I’ve had it working when I use the stmt_bind_param after setting buffer. My issue is that with a defined size at compile time I can alter the str_data and run execute again. This is not possible the way you suggest and pointing. For now I re run stmt_bind_param everytime I change str_data to make it match the content and buffer size of the set str_data.